# Using MVC EF add data to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf, entity-framework-4

MY web app call some methods through WCF,when I call a add method,the method has a foreach to add data to database.when it runs about 20+ times,it throw a exception as the follows:

```
The underlying provider failed on Open.
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
```

I use MVC4 and EF4.

```
 foreach(){ 
           CollDevValConRepository.Create(DB, quantity); 
           CollDevValConRepository.Save(DB);
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked if your connection string is correct?

Comment: As @Christos said, this error occurs when your connection is broken (_even if it used to work before_). For example, if your SQL server is down for any reason, or offline, or you don't have access (**yes, that can happen**), you will get this error.

Comment: Do you dispose when finish, and recreate the db object at the start?

Comment: 3q for your help.I'm sure the connection string is correct,because when I operate this,it has operate the database some times,and the web app is running,and I can do anything to operate the database.

Comment: the code is                    foreach(){     CollDevValConRepository.Create(DB, quantity);
                        CollDevValConRepository.Save(DB);} it throw errors when run the save method.

Comment: ef needs to hand dispose when finish and recreate the db?

Comment: can you share the code for `Create()` method ?

Comment: the create method code:        public virtual void Create(SysEntities db, T entity)
        {
            if (entity != null)
            {
                db.CreateObjectSet<T>().AddObject(entity);
            }
        }